# The best battery saving method for Location updates

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write an Adroid application that should run in background and notify the user when he will be close to the place given in the database. Should I do it by requestLocationUpdates in the extended IntentService class?

What is the best way to make it as least battery draining as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reto Meier has written extensively on this topic : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

There is also a section on `Optimizing Battery Life` at the Android Developers site: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html

Comment: Ok, I'll read both topics carefully tomorrow. But from the point of view of prefessional, should I use IntentService or just simple Activity with working updates when it's stopped?